# Sutiable post-hoc tests after Quade test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, post-hoc

What would be the most appropriate post-hoc test after a Quade omnibus test? Are any of these suitable?

- t-test with Bonferroni adjustment (potential problem: parametric, Quade is non-parametric)
- Holm
- Finner
- Hochberg
- Li